# Could I create a no parameter constructor when superclass has protected final field

Tags: java

I have a super class that has a protected final field, so it has to create a constructor with parameter, like this:

```
public SuperClass<ID> implements Serializable {
    protected final ID id;
    public SuperClass(ID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Then subclass also needs to create a constructor with parameter to initialize the inherited field.

```
public SubClass extends SuperClass<UUID> {
    public SubClass(UUID id) {
        super(id);
    }
}
```

Now I have a problem is I need a constructor without parameter for other use(e.g Jackson's deserialize). So is there any solution to solute this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If this is just for the Jackson de-serialize, then [this](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialize-immutable-objects) might help.

Comment: Jackson can use the constructor.

Comment: @AndrewS I considered to use the JsonCreator but my sub-class is an entity in the clean architecture, and I think the entity should not know and use this annotation which is not exactly related to business rules.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  You have to call the superclass's constructor with a value, since that's the only option you have.  But there's no reason that value has to come  from a parameter to your constructor:

```
public SubClass extends SuperClass<UUID> {
    public SubClass() {
        super(UUID.fromString("whatever");  // Exactly what you pass is up to you
    }
    public SubClass(UUID id) {
        super(id);
    }
}
```

PS: I'm not sure what that 'ID' type is that the superclass's constructor takes.  Did you mean `UUID`?

Comment: First, thanks for your answer. The ID in superclass is a generics but actually I use UUID when I construct a instance.